# Redux and create entity adapter - how to read an entity data?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, createentityadapter

I have create separate slice for entity adapters that I have inside of /redux/slices/messagesSlice.ts. When I try to access store from inside of that file it appears as undefined.

I need to access state (store.getState()) inside of my chatSelector.

On redux website they have all the code reducers and configurestore in one file.

My question is:

Do I need to import store into every component that wants to use selector.selectAll(store.getState()) ??

Answer (score 0):

A had the same question, and I find this post.

After some time and research, I realize something:

In the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) in the blue note on the top is written:

> For purposes of this reference, we will use Entity to refer to the
> specific data type that is being managed by a copy of the reducer
> logic in a specific portion of the Redux state tree, and entity to
> refer to a single instance of that type. Example: in state.users,
> Entity would refer to the User type, and state.users.entities[123]
> would be a single entity.

So for me below worked fine.

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

 const jobName = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.job.entities[props.id]?.jobName);
```